# CMD se cierra al evaluar condición

Tags: batch, .bat

Estoy comenzando a aprender algo sobre batch, quiero hacer un sencillo algoritmo que me permita buscar y contar cuantos archivos temporales hay y saber en cuantas carpetas buscó dichos archivos, posteriormente con la decisión del usuario entonces lo que hago es eliminar los temporales recorriendo las carpetas.

Como aun no conozco sobre los códigos de batch para hacer el archivo .bat, entonces me puse a buscar información, y encuentro que al evaluar una condición con IF, el programa se me cierra, un ejemplo es esto sencillo.

Ejemplo: Recibir dos variables por teclado y evaluar si los números son iguales o diferentes...

```
@echo off
echo.
set/p number= Escribe un numero 
cls 
set/p number2 = Escribe otro numero 
echo.

if %number%=%number2% (echo Son iguales) else (echo Son diferente)
echo.
pause >nul
```

El programa me recibe los dos números, pero al evaluar la consola se me cierra y no me deja ver nada. ¿Debo configurar algo?..

Gracias desde yá.

Comment: En  el IF la comparación se realiza con  dos  signos de igualdad == . IF %number% == %number2%

Comment: Gracias @JuanCarlosGuibovich, tienes razón, estoy fallando en los operadores lógicos , ya no se cierra la ventana del CMD, sin embargo no me muestra el resultado en paréntesis según la afirmación realizada.

Comment: Pero llega hasta el pause? Ah, pon entre comillas las variables "%number%" == "%number2%"

Comment: Si, así es... Llega hasta el pause, pero no me imprime lo que debería imprimir según la condición, no se, si quizás la manera de programar archivos.bat ha cambiado, pero me estoy guiando por un curso del año 2016, no logro encontrar contenido educativo sobre esta programación que sea reciente. Gracias por tu disposición y quedo atento si me puedes ayudar !

Comment: Las n comillas son opcionales relqmente , pero debería funcionar. Hazle un echo de las variable antes del if.

Comment: El  == está con espacios a los lados? Si está se los quitas y pruebas. Y la verdad que ya no veo nada más porque la línea del if es igual a la que está en tu pregunta pero esta vez ==. Cierto?

Comment: @JuanCarlosGuibovich Saludos, ya encontré cual era la falla. Resulta que cuando puse la variable `set/p number2 =` se me fue con un espacio separando el igual de la variable, al hacer el echo a las variables me mostró solo 1 y la otra me dijo que "El echo esta desactivado" y no mostró nada por ende el `if` no estaba funcionado ya que no recibía el valor de las dos variables. Ya solucione quitando el espacio entre las variables y el igual cuando las declaro.

Comment: Eso que has hecho ponlo como tú respuesta para que no que la pregunta en el aire. Explicas las dos cosa porque eso del SET le puede ocurrir a otra persona quizá.

Comment: Lo haré gracias por la sugerencia.

Answer (score 0):

Gracias a los comentarios de Juan Carlos Guibovich, logré encontrar la solución, un error en la escritura al declarar la segunda variable me estaba enviando una variable vacía, así como el uso incorrecto del operador lógico `==` estaba logrando que la ejecución saliese de control y se cerrara la ventana del CMD.

**OBSERVEMOS ES ESPACIO EN LA DECLARACION DE LA VARIABLE**
`set/p number2 = Escriba otro numero`

**SOLUCION**
`set/p number2= Escriba otro numero`
de ésta manera ya la variable toma el valor ingresado.

**SOLUCION AL USO DEL OPERADOR LOGICO**
`if %number%==%number2% (echo Son iguales) else (echo Son diferente)`

He realizado la prueba de las correcciones y ahora si que funciona el algoritmo comparando las dos variables e imprimiendo la respuesta.